# combining static library & framework in a single project

Tags: javascriptcore

I am using JavaScriptCore.a static library in my application since there was no JavaScriptCore.framework available from Apple before iOS 7. Now, I need to support iOS 7 as well as iOS 6 & earlier versions. I can continue to use the .a but in future I may want to move to JavaScriptCore.framework completely to avoid an app store approval concerns & hence, I want to start using both in a single project. Now, my problem is that, since both .a & .framework will have similar classes/symbols (not all the classes will be similar because .a is not the latest version), what is the impact on the application when it is loaded in memory?  What are the things that needs to be taken care of at compile time & run time. My implementation will have check at runtime for iOS 7, the framework will have weak reference.